# Social media functionality on website

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter

Im totally new to integrating social media with a website so this is a bit of a scattershot question. There is no doubt questions on here answering this already but as im not sure what im looking for yet, im not sure how to find them.

Okay so my company wants to promote their twitter and facebook profiles as customer service avenues, so users will ask questions on there rather than calling or emailing.

Ive built quite a funky page promoting this, however the links are literally just links to the facebook and twitter pages.

Is there a method to load a window to twitter or facebook from a website link that will prompt a user to type and submit a question to be submitted the the FB/twitter feed? Or is there a way to take content from a text box on site and pass this through to FB/Twitter?

Basically just looking for something slightly cooler and more user friendly than just dumping them on the companies FB or twitter page on click.

Cheers,

Comment: I think that's a terrible idea, to drive all of the frustrated customers to post about their issues publicly rather than have a private support system that wouldn't ruin the company's reputation. But yes, there is a way, and you will need to make a Facebook app/Twitter app, and get the proper permissions from your users that will allow you to post on behalf of them (something that they will likely feel very uncomfortable about), or you might consider at solutions that don't need permissions but will redirect your users to a different site or must be used in an iframe like Facebook's sharer.php

Comment: You could call the Send dialog with the id of your Facebook page already specified as recipient, so people can send private messages to your page. Those can be answered via the FB UI, or even via API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this website as an idea on pushing content into tweets
http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/

example for twitter: the href on your link would be:

https://twitter.com/home?status=your%20content%20here

if you wanted dynamic content, you would build the url using script.

same rules apply for facebook.

if you wanted to keep it within your website, maybe look into a fixed position div containing an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution I was looking for that works for twitter, its simply passing values through a URL, details are here https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#mention.

For facebook, seem to be able to do this through the comments module. Seems like a lot of this can be edited through the API so a combination of both should give me what i need:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/